# Rails 6.1 creating a record results only in UPDATE transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I’m attempting to upgrade from Rails 5.2 -> Rails 6.1. I’ve gotten all the dependencies sorted out, but am now running into an issue where my unit tests are failing because the tests do not seem to be able to create new records in our test sqlite3 1.4 DB.

Dependency Versions Updates:

```
bundler: 1.3.5 -> 2.2.27
rails (and all immediate Rails dependencies): 5.2.4.1 -> 6.1.4.1
byebug: 10.0.2 -> 11.0.1
pry: 0.11.3 -> 0.13.1
pry-byebug: 3.6.0 -> 3.9.0
sqlite3: 1.3.13 -> 1.4.2
sass-rails: 5.0.6 -> 6.0.0
haml-rails: 1.0.0 -> 2.0.0
haml: 5.0.4 -> 5.1.4
responders: 2.4.0 -> 3.0.1
bullet: 5.8.1 -> 6.1.4
jasmine-rails: 0.14.7 -> 0.15.0
actionpack-action_caching: 1.2.1 -> 1.2.2
concurrent-ruby-ext: 1.0.5 -> 1.1.9
delayed_job_active_record: 4.1.4 -> 4.1.6
```

When I insert a breakpoint into our tests, and attempt to do a simple create on a model, I see that `.save` or `.create` returns `true`, however, the record has no ID, and the count for that model remains unchanged. I have a similar experience when running save, as it returns true, even though the record was not actually saved. What’s strange is that running .valid? also returns true . Has anyone ever dealt with a similar issue before?

Debugging and showcasing the SQL reveals the following

```
@b.save!
-- :   TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
-- :   P Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "p".* FROM "p" WHERE "p"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
-- :   B Update (0.1ms)  UPDATE "b" SET "c_id" = ?, "d" = ?, "e" = ?, "f" = ?, "g" = ? WHERE "b"."id" IS NULL  [["c_id", 3], ["d", 0], ["e", 7], ["f", 200], ["g", "Z"]]
-- :   P Update (0.2ms)  UPDATE "p" SET "c" = ? WHERE "p"."id" = ?  [["c", "F"], ["id", 2]]
-- :   TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

The main thing to focus on is that calling `.save` on a new record results in an `UPDATE` transaction to table `B` instead of an `INSERT` operation.  The `before_save` callback can be seen to run successfully, but the `before_create` callback does not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being a problem with our use of the `protected_attributes_continued` gem

https://github.com/westonganger/protected_attributes_continued/pull/18

Upgrading `protected_attributes_continued` from 1.5 -> 1.6 fixed the issue